# showing ffplay in real-time

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, real-time

I am using ffplay (showcqt) from FFMPEG, in Linux, to analyse music compositions. Currently I have to record as an MP3 file then play the file through ffplay showcqt to see the visualisation, tweak and repeat.

Is it possible to bypass the MP3 file creation and take the realtime live input and have a permanently displayed showcqt visualiser?

If this were possible, I am sure I would dedicate a Raspberry Pi and plasma screen to permanently show this, so that I can constantly analyse the audio in real-time.

Thanks,

Phil

**May 2022 updated plea**

I thought that I would update this again to see if anyone has found a solution since 2020, when I first asked the question.

My Autonomou5 Youtube Channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_7n4p29Sq3_xyWxQMOZRQw shows how the FFPLAY displays a helpful FFT with note pitches, which is ideal for checking the pitches of the synths (and also makes a nice vid to upload the music to youtube).

However, I have to record the live audio, save to mp3 then use FFPLAY on the saved audio file, which I then record to video.

This is the ffplay CLI code:-

`ffplay -f lavfi 'amovie=AudioFile.mp3, asplit [a][out1]; [a] showcqt=fps=30:count=5:text=1 [out0]'`

I would really appreciate any tips, suggestions or hints to be able to display the FFPLAY live. Such as; streaming the audio and using FFPLAY with the stream as the source. I have no experience in streaming and do not even know if this would work.

Has anyone managed to run FFPLAY on live audio?

Comment: What's your input device?

Comment: Hi Gyan, My input device is nothing special, pulse audio via a Dell Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip ID: 8086:1c20.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on producing a realtime display with ffplay? I am happy to investigate further if someone can point me in a specific direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about other sound systems, but I managed to do this using pulseaudio. With pulseaudio, all sinks have a corresponding "monitor" source that can be recorded or analysed. You can list all sources, including the monitors corresponding to output devices using the command

```
pactl list sources short
```

Once you have the name (or number) of the monitor corresponding to your output device (`alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor` in my case), you can visualize it in the following way:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel quiet -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor -f nut pipe: \
  | ffplay -f lavfi -i 'amovie=pipe\\:,showspectrum=size=2560x1440:mode=separate:scale=cbrt:color=cividis [out0]'
```

If the visualization noticably lags behind the audio, you can try adding some latency-improving flags to ffplay from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49273163/5613485). For me, `-fflags nobuffer` did the trick.

You can use any visualization filter, `showspectrum` is just an example, the `showcqt` filter that you mentioned in the question works too. However, if the filter copies its audio to its output too, it needs to be muted (with the `-an` option or with the `volume` filter), otherwise it will be played back on the output device and cause a feedback loop. For example:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel quiet -f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor -f nut pipe: \
  | ffplay -an -fflags nobuffer -f lavfi -i 'amovie=pipe\\:,ebur128=video=1 [out0][out1]'
```

It would be nice to get rid of `ffmpeg` in the command and use only `ffplay` but I could not find a way to do so.

Comment: Hi Zoltan, Thank you for your response. It is an excellent solution that worked perfectly for me. Thank you. Sorry that it took 2 months to respond.

Comment: No problem! If this solution worked for you, you may consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the gray check mark to the left of it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).